# Custom module configs are not loading in DXA 1.4

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.4, dxa-1.5

I was trying to make my existing [JWPlayer](https://community.sdl.com/products-solutions/solutions/customer_experience_cloud/digital-experience/tridion/tridion-developer/m/mediagallery/1412) module compatible with latest release of DXA. but i am having issues doing so.

In `BinaryData\17\system\config` `jwplayer.schemas.json` is not downloading, only `core.schemas.json`, i debug the code but did not find any code to download the custom module config files.

Reference to files is also zero in `LocalizationData.cs`
[image]

So, i browsed the GitHub and compared `localization.cs` file & found following code snippet is missing from 1.3 + version, May be it has been moved somewhere else.

[image]

do anybody know the reason of not loading those files, due to which custom module is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since DXA 1.3, loading of config files is done "on-demand" (i.e. when config values are needed) instead of upfront (at "bootstrap" time). This improves startup performance.

So, indeed, the `LocalizationData.ConfigStaticContentUrls` property is not used anymore; config files are loaded when needed in `Localization.LoadConfigSection`.

AFAIK, config files named `config\{module}.schemas.json` are only used in `DefaultProvider.MapSchema` (which, in turn, is used by `DefaultProvider.PopulateDynamicList`) in order to translate a Semantic Schema symbolic name to a Schema ID (number).

For other semantic mapping purposes, the file `mapping\schemas.json` is used (and that one is supposed to contain semantic mapping data for all Schemas in all active modules).

Comment: I thought same that it could be on demand, but my module which i created in 1.2 was not working so when i added below mentioned method, it is working fine. so not sure what trigger dxa to load the configs? could you clarify? or any change in the way module are created in 1.3+

Comment: As mentioned, the config files are loaded as soon as a config value in them is accessed. See `Localization.GetConfigValue`.

Comment: Looks like working for me now, one module error was causing other modules to load.

Answer (score 0):

After adding following method to Localization.cs, solved a bit but `mappings/schema.json` still not including schema fields from modules, no sure hows other modules are working post DXA 1.2

```
 private void LoadConfig(IEnumerable<string> configItemUrls)
        {
            _config = new Dictionary<string, IDictionary<string, string>>();
            foreach (string configItemUrl in configItemUrls)
            {
                string sectionName = configItemUrl.Substring(configItemUrl.LastIndexOf("/", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1);
                sectionName = sectionName.Substring(0, sectionName.LastIndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal)).ToLower();
                string jsonData = SiteConfiguration.ContentProvider.GetStaticContentItem(configItemUrl, this).GetText();
                Dictionary<string, string> settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonData);
                _config.Add(sectionName, settings);
            }
        }
```